# How would I build and link an external library using CMake?

Tags: cmake

To start off, I should say that I've seen the answers on questions that were similar to mine, yet none of them seem to make sense to me. Here goes:

Say I have the following simple CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Example)
add_executable (Example Main.cpp)
```

I would then like to link a library that already has its own CMakeLists (for example, [glfw](https://github.com/glfw/glfw)) against `Example`. Of course, this brings into question how to properly set up the build order.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me describe what to do for GLFW. See the notes below for variations.

1. Build GLFW. As the official GLFW head's CMake support is [currently broken](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/460), use this shaxbee fork:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/shaxbee/glfw.git
   cmake -Hglfw -Bbuild/glfw -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=inst -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
   cmake --build build/glfw --target install --config Release
   ```

This install step installs `inst/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake`, the `glfw3` config-module which will be used by client projects to find GLFW.

2. Your project should look like this:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
   project(Example)
   find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
   add_executable(Example Main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(Example glfw3)
   ```

The `find_package` command finds the `glfw3Config.cmake` which creates an `IMPORTED` library, a CMake target, which incorporates all the information needed to use GLFW in your project.
The `target_link_libraries` command tells CMake not only to link to GLFW but to use its include directories and compile flags, too.

3. Configure your project with `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=inst` (use full path if necessary)

Note: Other config-modules or find-modules may not provide `IMPORTED` targets. See the actual config or find-module for help. They usually provide `<PACKAGE>_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `<PACKAGE>_LIBRARIES` variables which should be added to the appropriate settings of your target:

```
    target_include_directories(mytarget ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

or

```
    include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Same for `target_link_libraries` / `link_libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Build the external dependency first.
2. add a function call to find your external library. That can either be FindGLFW.cmake with `find_package` if you can find that or write it yourself using `find_library` et al. More information about including external libraries can be found in the [CMake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries)
3. Add the includes and libraries to your `Example` executable.

This is how CMake should be used, I don't see why is not answered in the sources in the Internet.